# Save a model weights when a program receives TIME LIMIT while learning on a SLURM cluster

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cluster-computing, slurm, pytorch-lightning

I use a deep learning models written in pytorch_lightning (pytorch) and train them on slurm clusters. I submit job like this:

```
sbatch --gpus=1 -t 100 python train.py
```

When requested `GPU` time ends, slurm kills my program and shows such message:

```
Epoch 0: : 339it [01:10,  4.84it/s, loss=-34]  slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 375083 ON cn-007 CANCELLED AT 2021-10-04T22:20:54 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

How can I configure a Trainer to save model when available time end?

I know about [automatic saving](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/weights_loading.html#automatic-saving) after each epoch, but I have only one long epoch that lasts >10 hours, so this case is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Slurm's signalling mechanism to pass a signal to your application when it's within a certain number of seconds of the timelimit (see `man sbatch`). In your submission script use `--signal=USR1@30` to send `USR1` 30 seconds before the timelimit is reached. Your submit script would contain these lines:

```
#SBATCH -t 100
#SBATCH --signal=USR1@30
srun python train.py
```

Then, in your code, you can handle that signal like this:

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler got signal ', signum)
    # e.g. exit(0), or call your pytorch save routines

# enable the handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)

# your code here
```

You need to call your Python application via `srun` in order for Slurm to be able to propagate the signal to the Python process. (You can probably use `--signal` on the command line to `sbatch`, I tend to prefer writing self-contained submit scripts :))

Edit: [This link](https://dhruveshp.com/blog/2021/signal-propagation-on-slurm/) has a nice summary of the issues involved with signal propagation and Slurm.

Comment: Will `srun`  launch my program in interactive mode or in batch mode?

Comment: via a batch script, it'll be batch mode. I'm not sure ifthe signal handling works the same way in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that preemption wont be an issue you can also just set a [`max_time`](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/trainer.html#max-time) when initializing the trainer.

e.g.:

```
# Stop after 12 hours
trainer = Trainer(max_time="00:12:00:00")
```

You could set this to a static value or get it from the [SLURM environment variables](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_SLURM_JOB_END_TIME).